# order of 2>&1 when redirecting std error to file

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I'm seeing some different formats for redirecting std output to a file :

```
a.  command 1&2>output.txt
b.  command >output.txt 2>&1
c.  command 2>&1>output.txt  
d.  command &>output.txt
```

Is there any difference between these? 
If `2>&1` is placed at the end (b) , how does it redirect the stderr of the first command ?

Comment: `(a)` is wrong and does not work. `(c)` does not redirect stderr to stdin

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The order matters. `>` may bring up the idea of pointing and pointers/references and so does the word "redirect", but fd redirections are more like assignments.
That is, if you do

`exec 2>&1 1>output.txt`

It will "assign" the current "value" (the actual file opened with that file descriptor) of file descriptor `1` to file descriptor `2`  and then open `output.txt` and assign it to file descriptor `1`.

What it won't do is point `&2` (read & as "file descriptor") to `&1`. It won't make accessing `&2` query `&1`.
A file descriptor is only ever associated with an actual file, never with another file descriptor. `2>&1` associates the file now opened under `&1` with `&2`. It doesn't redirect `&2` to `&1` in the sense that writing to `&2` would make it write to what `&1` is associated with at the moment. `&1` can later be reopened with a different file that what it was associated with at the time of the `2>&1` redirection, but that won't affect what `&2` writes to.

Check out [dup2(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) if you want to know how this functionality is exposed at the system call level.